# Metered wi-fi connection on Android tablet?

Tags: wi-fi, tablet, data-monitoring

I have a non-rooted Nexus 7 (2013), and connect to the internet via a Mi-Fi hotspot.

I have a low data cap, so I need to track usage closely. I'd like to be able to mark my connection as metered, but since this is a tablet, those options don't exist in Data Usage.

Is there any app or alternative method to enable that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

At least on my Nexus 10:

Settings → Data Usage → ⋮ menu → Network Restrictions

brings up a screen where you can set whether each WiFi network is metered or not.

Comment: OP wrote: "*but since this is a tablet, those options don't exist in Data Usage*"

Comment: @Firelord I just checked on my Nexus 10, which is also very much a tablet. They exist.

Comment: Please state the UI software and version you are using, and if it is customised by your network, along with Android version. Things vary a lot between models/versions.

Comment: @Tyeth you realize this is an almost 5-year old answer? Also, how it was a Nexus 10 — so there was only one version, it runs basically stock Android, and it's a Wi-Fi only device...

Comment: Yep, saw the date, but I am in a similar boat where the option appeared to have been hidden from the settings / removed in an update. I had forgotten the nexus was wifi only, so just the two android versions listed as released, so thanks for that bit!

Comment: @Tyeth it still exists on my Pixel 3a on Android 11 (though in a different spot). This question is about finding it on a Nexus 7, maybe ask a new question about your device?

Answer (score 0):

I'm equally searching for another option as my phone keeps forgetting the metered networks immediately after I set them, google has alot of noise on the issue pointing to the inbuilt feature.

Try using Netguard from Google Play. Its working for me. Appeared on Make use of article:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/prevent-any-app-using-mobile-data-android/