# Is it possible to designate a Wi-FI SSID as metered "mobile network"?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data, 9.0-pie, data-connection

I am wondering if there is a method by which I can designate a WLAN/WiFi connection as "mobile network" based on its SSID for the sake data usage policies by apps or the Android system in general.

Typically when you have a data plan with your mobile provider, your phone's LTE (or  3G ...) modem will connect to the provider to enable you to have internet access.

Now if I am using a mobile LTE/WLAN router instead, my phone assumes that it's on an unmetered WiFi uplink and apps/the system will (mis)behave accordingly.

Is there a way to tell the system that when it connects to a particular SSID it should treat that as "mobile network" in regards to how apps may use data?

Phone: Samsung S9+ (SM-G965F), Android 9

NB: the settings [from this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144167/9993) don't exist on my phone.

Answer (score 5):

This option actually exists and I have just tested it on Android 10 (AOSP). The trick is to set a custom DHCP option 43 with the text value "ANDROID_METERED". What I find a bit confusion is that Android does not show you that it is on a metered Wi-Fi. I verified it with the [NetworkMonitor app](https://github.com/caarmen/network-monitor).

Someone documented this further: https://www.lorier.net/docs/android-metered.html

Comment: +1 Helpful only if WiFi router allows to configure custom DHCP option 43 which must not be the case with many routers.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder if that option gets set when you open a hotspot on one device and another connects to that hotspot. Gotta experiment a little.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think WiFi can be designated as a Mobile Network, but stock Android provides option to set WiFi network as metered. When connected to the WiFi, go to that WiFi connection settings and you will find options to set the connection `metered` or `unmetered` (at least on Pie).

[image]

OEMs might be removing the option from GUI. You can also try CLI method as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/data-saver#testing). From `adb shell` execute:

```
~$ cmd netpolicy set metered-network <WIFI_SSID> true
```