# Hosting a hotspot without signaling metered connection

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

Currently, I am running a hotspot from an Android phone as my home network. The cellular plan for this phone has unlimited data.

When I host the hotspot, connected devices detect that this hotspot has a cellular connection behind it, and treats it as a cellular connection. This, for example, limits connected Android phones to not back up photos via Google Photos if the "back up over cellular data" option isn't enabled.

**Can I somehow edit the way the hotspot is being run, so that it doesn't signal to connected devices that there is a cellular connection in the background?**

The hosting phone is rooted, and I have no trouble using a terminal-based setup (with hostapd or similar)

EDIT:
Additional information:

```
 raphael:/ # netstat -lntup | grep -E ':53|:67'
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22525/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 192.168.166.70:53       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22525/dnsmasq
tcp6       0      0 2a00:801:237:80f8::c:53 :::*                    LISTEN      22525/dnsmasq
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      22525/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           17668/mdnsd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           22525/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 192.168.166.70:53       0.0.0.0:*                           22525/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           2243/com.android.networkstack.process
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                17668/mdnsd
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                17668/mdnsd
udp6       0      0 2a00:801:237:80f8::c:53 :::*                                22525/dnsmasq
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                22525/dnsmasq

raphael:/ # cat /proc/22525/cmdline                                                                                      
/system/bin/dnsmasq--keep-in-foreground--no-resolv--no-poll--dhcp-authoritative--dhcp-option-force=43,ANDROID_METERED--pid
```

Comment: It's because Android's DHCP server sends `ANDROID_METERED` DHCP option to connected clients. You can set connection unmetered on connected hosts, see screenshot in this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215528/218526

Comment: Thank you! I was looking to implement it from the hotspot side (to avoid having to change every connected device), but this is a step along the way!

Comment: Which Androis version your hotspot device is running? If it's Android 9 or earlier you can edit `dnsmasq` commandline arguments. I can write a bit detailed answer. What does `netstat -lntup | grep -E ':53|:67'` and `pgrep -a dmsmasq` return when hotspot is on?

Comment: The hotspot phone is running Android 11, so that might be a problem. I edited my original post with output of the commands you wrote.

Comment: Unfortunately both commands you have run don't provide the info I'm looking for. Run `netstat` with root so that last column is not empty. `pgrep` was supposed to show the running `dnsmasq` process. Instead you can try `cat /proc/$(pgrep dnsmasq)/cmdline`. // You can use https://pastebin.com to share command output.

Comment: I thought that was the case. I've updated it with more reasonable outputs now. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. `dnsmasq` is listening on port 53, as DNS server. But on port 67 Android's Java stack is listening as DHCP server, as expected. So it's not a straightforward option to remove `ANDROID_METERED` option, as we can do with `dnsmasq` on Android 9 and earlier versions. Still there is a possibility to manipulate DHCP options using third party software like [dhcpoptinj](https://github.com/misje/dhcpoptinj). However I've never tried this.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tip about injecting dhcp options, I'll check it out!

Comment: Another option is not to use Android's hotspot feature at all. Instead create hotspot from commandline. This answer may help: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217896/218526

Comment: Thanks, I actually saw that post, but my device (running an AOSP-based ROM) didn't have iw and some of the other commands mentioned in the guide.

Comment: I've all of the 4 statically built binaries. But I don't think they are missing in any Android release. Android framework itself rely on these binaries under the hood. Check your `/system` and `/vendor` in depth.

Comment: I did a 'find / -name "iw"' and nothing came up, but maybe its hidden somewhere...

Comment: Might be. Exceptions may exist.